# Is there any difference made between "мог (могла)", "мог бы (могла бы)", "возможно бы", "возможно было", "возможно было бы" in certain contexts?

Tags: грамматика

If we take the sentence "I could have gone to college, but I decided to take a profitable job on a construction site", I think it could be rendered in Russian as follows:

1. Я мог учиться в колледже, но решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.
2. Я мог бы учиться в колледже, но решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.
3. Я возможно бы учился в колледже, но решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.
4. Для меня возможно было учиться в колледже, но я решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.
5. Для меня возможно было бы учиться в колледже, но я решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.

I personally don't see any differences between these translations.

Considering my having possibly been misled, and the particle "бы" not expressing the conditional mood here, it must nevertheless be playing *some* role.

What is that role of "бы" here?

Comment: I can't speak for the Russian, but in English, *could* in that sentence isn't conditional; it's the past tense of *can* meaning that the speaker *had the opportunity* to go to school, but opted instead to work construction.

Comment: @CocoPop Thank you very much for "had the opportunity". It has arrived pat on target.

Comment: Couldn't you put me on to which parts of my original text may be reckoned grammatically correct, thow laboured, forced and non-idiomatic? And which are unacceptable in terms of grammar at all?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. The things I left alone are grammatically acceptable and idiomatic. The things I changed... needed changing.

Comment: @CocoPop For example, I would have been interested to know if "Will there be any difference...", "Taking up the sentence...",  "As for me, I can't tell if there are...", "I would think that it can be rendered...", "it may nevertheless be playing some role" were grammatically acceptable, though unidiomatic?

Comment: Yes, they're all grammatical (if not a bit wordy), but unidiomatic in this context.

Comment: @CocoPop Thank you!

Comment: The particle “бы” indicates an alternative option compared to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Я мог бы учиться в колледже, но решил взяться за доходную работу на стройке.

First of all, let's talk about бы.

Besides conditional sentences, бы has some modal meanings: hypothetical, suppositional opportunity, necessity, etc. Here we have an opportunity, don't we?

All the other variations seem unnatural.

I just tried to come up with any other correct sentence I could think of. Here the register is more official.

У меня была возможность учиться в ....

Comment: Could you put me up to which of the patterns may be thought of as forced, far-fetched? And what would you think of something like this: "Я может быть бы в колледже бы учился,..."?

Comment: *Could you **tell me** which of the patterns...

Comment: I believe one бы will do, and it is better to change the verb for поучился.But it is still просторечие (common parlance). And all the variations with возможно are as you say за уши притянутые --- far-fetched.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for #2, "я мог бы учиться в ". However, additionally:

1 I'd use a perfect, rather than imperfect, verb.

2 in contemporary Russian usage, "колледж" is not what we usually mean by "college" in English.

So I prefer "я мог бы поступить (or пойти) в университет".

Comment: This particle "бы" is what I am not taking in to the fullest. With "could have gone" not being a 3rd Conditional here, the idea it is conveying can be gotten across like this (I've cut down the pattern a little): "I could have gone to college, but finally I decided not to do that" = "It had been possible for me to go to college, but finally I decided not to do that" = "It had been possible that I would go to college, but finally I decided not to do that" ≈ "I had had the ability (I had been capable of)  to go to college, but finally I decided not to do that".

Comment: What is that tinge which "бы" imparts to the language in this and similar contexts?